# Session Variables Lost After 3rd Redirection

Tags: php, session

I have a project with several different pages in it. It used to work pretty well till I'have updated my PHP version. I don't remember previous version but current version is: 5.6.0beta4.

I can successfully login and see the index page. I can also resirect to a 2nd page from here, but when I try to redirect a 3rd page (it might be index page or any other pager) all my session values are being destroyed. This is how I do things;

Login;

```
session_start();
session_regenerate_id();
$_SESSION["user"] = "testuser";
$_SESSION["enter"] = true;
$_SESSION["id"] = 1;
header("location: index.php");
exit();
```

In other pages I use forms to redirect;

```
<table border=0>
<form method=post action=second.php name=second>
<input type=submit value="2nd Page">
</form><br/>
<form method=post action=third.php name=third>
<input type=submit value="3rd Page">
</form>
</table>
```

All of my pages start with session_start() and session_regenerate_id().

Any help is welcome. I have done some research on Internet but all of the information is based on lack of session_start() function. I believe my problem is more related with php.ini. As I said, this session system used to work perfectly. Here is my session values;

---

```
    session.auto_start               Off           Off
    session.cache_expire             180           180
    session.cache_limiter            nocache       nocache
    session.cookie_domain            no value      no value
    session.cookie_httponly          Off           Off
    session.cookie_lifetime          1440          1440
    session.cookie_path              /             /
    session.cookie_secure            Off           Off
    session.entropy_file             /dev/urandom  /dev/urandom
    session.entropy_length           32            32
    session.gc_divisor               1000          1000
    session.gc_maxlifetime           1440          1440
    session.gc_probability           1             1
    session.hash_bits_per_character  5             5
    session.hash_function            0             0
    session.name                     PHPSESSID     PHPSESSID
    session.referer_check            no value      no value
    session.save_handler             files         files
    session.save_path                /var/lib/php5 /var/lib/php5
    session.serialize_handler        php           php
    session.upload_progress.cleanup  On            On
    session.upload_progress.enabled  On            On
    session.upload_progress.freq     1%            1%
    session.upload_progress.min_freq 1             1
    session.upload_progress.name     PHP_SESSION_UPLOAD_PROGRESS PHP_SESSION_UPLOAD_PROGRESS
    session.upload_progress.prefix   upload_progress_ upload_progress_
    session.use_cookies              On            On
    session.use_only_cookies         On            On
    session.use_strict_mode          Off           Off
    session.use_trans_sid            0             0
```

Comment: Why are you always using session_regenerate_id() ? To start, try without these calls. And do not forget that you'r using a beta version it can be a problem too.

Comment: And do you have `session_start()` on *said* other pages?

Comment: I will try without session regenerate id and share the results. It was used for security concerns. Yes I also have session start on the beginning of every php file.

Comment: I've tried removing session_regenerate_id() from pages but it has no effect

Comment: it has been fixed randomly, I believe it was a problem with beta PHP.